# Full example of container deployment with fabric8 api

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, fabric8

I am looking for a complete example that explains the deployment of application container using the fabric8 java API. What should be the execution order of the following concepts?

1. Service
2. Replication Controller
3. Pod
4. Docker container

And how to configure them together?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please read the [kubernetes user-guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/) for the basic concepts in kubernetes, and [tutorials](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/) for examples and common usage patterns.

In a nutshell, docker containers are hidden in Pods. You don't just create containers; you create a Pod in which there are co-located containers. Alternatively, you can create a replication controller which creates/deletes pods to meet your desired replica number.

The common usage is to create a service, and then a replication controller to manage the pods which are endpoints of the service. The details vary based on the applications.

Comment: Both links are 404 :(